# Class _PointQueue is implemented in both when I click on textfield... How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, uitextfield

I'm using xcode 13 and making a demo on coredata.

> objc[6188]: Class _PathPoint is implemented in both
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
> (0x114a8fa78) and
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI
> (0x12cd4a8b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> objc[6188]: Class _PointQueue is implemented in both
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
> (0x114a8fa50) and
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI
> (0x12cd4a8d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Are you having any problems in your app or your code when this happens?

Comment: I have that error when showing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609835/swiftui-searchable-not-able-to-keep-focus-and-show-keyboard

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apple developer *Quinn “The Eskimo!” @ Developer Technical Support @ Apple* answered this question [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691361):

> This is not an error per se. Rather, it’s the Objective-C runtime telling you that:
>
> - Two frameworks within your process implement the same class (well, in this case classes, namely _PathPoint and _PointQueue).
> - The runtime will use one of them, choosing it in an unspecified way.
>
> This can be bad but in this case it’s not. Both of the implementations are coming from the system (well, the simulated system) and thus you’d expect them to be in sync and thus it doesn’t matter which one the runtime uses.
>
> So, in this specific case, these log messages are just [log noise](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115461).

Comment: I am seeing above often in the Debug Area in my Playground. If there was an easy way to not see it anymore I would appreciate it.

Comment: This really isn't a good answer, there should be resolution to this, even if it has to be taken to Apple.

Comment: @JohnPitts "resolution" to what? Quoted above is Apple response. SO yes, it was taken to Apple, and Apple basically tells us to ignore it.

Comment: It's totally an error, but it's Apple's error, not the programmer's.  It's good that it doesn't cause us problems beyond log noise (which ***is*** a problem, albeit a pretty small one), but Apple should be fixing this so that their code doesn't complain about its own behavior. You can generate the message by opening safari in a split screen with your app; when the keyboard comes up so you can type in the address bar in the browser, the error appears. Makes no difference what your app does or doesn't do.  Poor form, Apple.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually happens when you add a gesture recognizer inside a view that also has a gesture recognizer of its own. In your case, you may have added the textField as a subview of a view that has some sort of gesture recognizer, or scroll. So when you tap on that textField, it does not know which gesture to trigger. So, look into your implemetation and figure out if the textView is inside another view that has a geture.

In my case, I created a view, which had a gesture recognizer, and this view had a UITextView() as a subview. So when the parent view was tapped and the gestured was used, I would get this error. I solved it by disabling user interaction on my textView.

```swift
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using Rosetta to open Xcode 13.1.

After disabling the option "open with Rosetta" those errors were gone.

Answer (score -2):

I was getting the same error. I had hyperlink in textView

--> ex "I’ve read the [Privacy Notice](https://test.com) ..."

Then I realized that the link I entered into the hyperlink must meet the universal conditions. My hyperlink is;

wrong case --> "https://www.AçıkRıza.com"

true case --> "https://www.acikriza.com"

I was then able to build it successfully.

Comment: So `_PathPoint` was reported as duplicate only when you used the invalid URL? Sound improbable as this kind of warnings are logged at application startup, and have little to do with conditions that occur during the app lifetime, like yours universal link.

Comment: In my case yes, but this error can be from many different scenarios. I got similar textview error  **" ... TextInputUI (0x12cd4a8d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined"**. It solved my problem, maybe it will help.