# Searchable not able to keep focus and show keyboard

Tags: swiftui, searchable

I have the following code:

```
struct FocusStateTestView: View {
    
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
    
            Text("FocusStateTestView")
            
            Button {
                showSheet.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("present sheet")
            }

            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SheetTestView()
        }
    }
}


struct SheetTestView: View {
    
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                
                Text("hello")
                
            }
            .searchable(text: $text)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The sheet presents fine:

[image]

**Problem:**

keyboard does not show up. I cannot type in that text search textfield.

When the sheet is presented the console logs this:

`2022-03-24 15:40:11.230674-0600 myApp[92118:2113819] [UIFocus] Failed to update focus with context <UIFocusUpdateContext: 0x6000026bc8c0: previouslyFocusedItem=(null), nextFocusedItem=(null), focusHeading=None>. No additional info available. 2022-03-24 15:40:13.455689-0600 myApp[92118:2113819] [UIFocus] Deferring focus update to item <UISearchBarTextField: 0x14c89da00>. No additional info available. 2022-03-24 15:40:13.455920-0600 myApp[92118:2113819] [UIFocus] Failed to update focus with context <UIFocusUpdateContext: 0x6000026b7660: previouslyFocusedItem=(null), nextFocusedItem=(null), focusHeading=None>. No additional info available.`

I then try to tap on the search field, and the console shows this:

`objc[92118]: Class _PathPoint is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x12b85f338) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x1395d4fe8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[92118]: Class _PointQueue is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x12b85f310) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x1395d5010). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. 2022-03-24 15:40:26.005733-0600 myApp[92118:2113819] [UIFocus] Deferring focus update to item <UISearchBarTextField: 0x14c89da00>. No additional info available. 2022-03-24 15:40:26.005824-0600 myApp[92118:2113819] [UIFocus] Failed to update focus with context <UIFocusUpdateContext: 0x60000269d9a0: previouslyFocusedItem=(null), nextFocusedItem=(null), focusHeading=None>. No additional info available.`

Interestingly enough, the same code works on iPhone. I still get some weird logs about it when on iPhone:

`objc[92218]: Class _PathPoint is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x12aff7338) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x13f380fe8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. objc[92218]: Class _PointQueue is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x12aff7310) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x13f381010). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. 2022-03-24 15:43:25.454520-0600 myApp[92218:2116972] [HardwareKeyboard] -[UIApplication getKeyboardDevicePropertiesForSenderID:shouldUpdate:usingSyntheticEvent:], failed to fetch device property for senderID (778835616971358211) use primary keyboard info instead. 2022-03-24 15:43:25.457774-0600 myApp[92218:2116972] [HardwareKeyboard] -[UIApplication getKeyboardDevicePropertiesForSenderID:shouldUpdate:usingSyntheticEvent:], failed to fetch device property for senderID (778835616971358211) use primary keyboard info instead.`

But on iPhone at least it works.

How can I fix this? How can I properly present the keyboard on the iPad and search??

I have the same problem both on simulator and device. running Xcode Version 13.3 (13E113).

Comment: I can confirm this behavior, and it looks like a bug. I would file a Radar with Apple. The only thing I can think of to get around it is just to put a `TextField` on to the sheet, and use that instead, at least for the iPad.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved it by adding this:

```
.searchable(text: $text, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
```

It changes search bar's appearance a little, but it works for me.